# Scheduled Vertex AI Output to Big Query

Tags: web-scraping, google-bigquery, schedule, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I can run code manually in vertex to push code to BQ, but when I schedule the code the output table is not pushed to BQ.

No errors are listed, but neither does it record the code as having been run (although I can see it is scheduled).

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Set up the BigQuery client
client = bigquery.Client()

# Define the BigQuery table details
dataset_id = 'scraper_pool'
table_id = 'price_scraper'
table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('title', 'STRING', mode='nullable'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('created', 'STRING', mode='nullable'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('price', 'FLOAT', mode='nullable'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('sku', 'STRING', mode='nullable'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('available', 'BOOLEAN', mode='nullable'),
    bigquery.SchemaField('retrieval_date', 'DATE', mode='nullable'),
]

# Define the URLs to scrape
urls = ['https://www.twowheelsempire.com/products.json?limit=250&page=1']

# Scrape the data and load it into BigQuery
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    products = data["products"]

    rows = []
    for item in data["products"]:
        title = item["title"]
        created = item["created_at"]
        product_type = item["product_type"]
        for variant in item["variants"]:
            price = float(variant["price"])  # Cast price to float
            sku = str(variant["sku"])  # Cast sku to string
            available = bool(variant["available"])  # Cast available to boolean

            row = {'title': str(title),
                   'created': str(created),
                   'price': float(price),
                   'sku': str(sku),
                   'available': bool(available),
                   'retrieval_date': date.today().isoformat()} # Add the current date to the row data
            rows.append(row)

    # Create a new BigQuery table and load the data
    # Create a new BigQuery table and load the data
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(schema=schema, write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
    job = client.load_table_from_json(rows, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
    job.result()
```

I expected the code to push a new table to BQ. The code will manually run and it doesnt record any errors in the schedule, but nor does it appear to have actually run.

Comment: You might want to check the authentications to access BigQuery from the custom job on [Vertex AI with service account](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/custom-service-account). The service account that Vertex AI uses to access other is `service-[PROJECT_NUMBER]@gcp-sa-aiplatform.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

Comment: Not sure if your question has anything to do with writing to BQ. Are you able to schedule it without that step and does that run successfully?